# How to use ffmpeg to create a video from images with timestamps

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am attempting to record videos from a camera (basler pylon). Each frame has a timestamp provided by the camera. I want to write every frame into a video file one by one and set the interval time between two consecutive frames (in other words, fps) to match the interval time of their timestamps.I found an example code that uses ffmpeg to write the frame with a specified fps, but I am unsure how to modify the code to change it from specifying fps to using the timestamp of the frame. As I don't know anything about ffmpeg, could someone show me how to modify the code to achieve this? It should be noted that since I immediately write every image I obtain into a video, the solution of first obtaining all the images and then merging them into a video may not be feasible.

```py
class FFMPEG_VideoWriter:
    def __init__(
            self,
            filename,  # Use avi format if possible
            size,  # (width, height)
            fps,  # Frame rate
            codec="libx264",  # Codec
            audiofile=None,  # Audio file
            preset="medium",  # Compression rate; slower is better
            bitrate=None,  # Bitrate (set only when codec supports bitrate)
            pixfmt="rgba",
            logfile=None,
            threads=None,
            ffmpeg_params=None,
    ):
        if logfile is None:
            logfile = sp.PIPE

        self.filename = filename
        self.codec = codec
        self.ext = self.filename.split(".")[-1]

        # order is important
        cmd = [
            "ffmpeg",
            "-y",
            "-loglevel",
            "error" if logfile == sp.PIPE else "info",
            "-f",
            "rawvideo",
            "-vcodec",
            "rawvideo",
            "-s",
            "%dx%d" % (size[1], size[0]),
            "-pix_fmt",
            pixfmt,
            "-r",
            "%.02f" % fps,
            "-i",
            "-",
            "-an",
        ]
        cmd.extend(
            [
                "-vcodec",
                codec,
                "-preset",
                preset,
            ]
        )
        if ffmpeg_params is not None:
            cmd.extend(ffmpeg_params)
        if bitrate is not None:
            cmd.extend(["-b", bitrate])
        if threads is not None:
            cmd.extend(["-threads", str(threads)])

        if (codec == "libx264") and (size[0] % 2 == 0) and (size[1] % 2 == 0):
            cmd.extend(["-pix_fmt", "yuv420p"])
        cmd.extend([filename])

        popen_params = {"stdout": sp.DEVNULL, "stderr": logfile, "stdin": sp.PIPE}

        if os.name == "nt":
            popen_params["creationflags"] = 0x08000000  # CREATE_NO_WINDOW

        self.proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)

    def write_frame(self, img_array):
        """Writes one frame in the file."""
        try:
            self.proc.stdin.write(img_array.tobytes())
        except IOError as err:
            ...
            raise IOError(error)

    def close(self):
        if self.proc:
            self.proc.stdin.close()
            if self.proc.stderr is not None:
                self.proc.stderr.close()
            self.proc.wait()
        self.proc = None

    # Support the Context Manager protocol, to ensure that resources are cleaned up.

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()

# Use Example
with FFMPEG_VideoWriter(video_path, (height, width), fps=120, pixfmt="rgb24") as writer:
    while self.isRecording or not self.frame_queue.empty():
        if not self.frame_queue.empty():
            writer.write_frame(self.frame_queue.get())
```